# How can I upload/resize images taken with a digital camera?

Tags: php, image, gd, imagemagick

I am working on a building a gallery and the goal is a low barrier of entry.  My user is someone who takes pictures using their digital camera so file size would be between 200 - 400 KB per image.

The problem I am running into using the GD library is that each image when resized and uploaded use about 90MB of memory+ when the server has a 64 MB limit.

When I use ImageMagick it times out and throws an internal server error.

I am wondering if anyone has any experience with uploading/resizing such large image sizes and could give me some pointers.

Thanks,
Levi

edit: Here is my code to upload

```
     /** Begin Multiple Image Upload**/     
        $numberImages = count($_FILES['galFile']['name'])-1;

for($i=1;$i<=$numberImages;$i++)
{
$imageName = $_FILES['galFile']['name'][$i];
            $imageType = $_FILES['galFile']['type'][$i];
            $imageSize = $_FILES['galFile']['size'][$i];
            $imageTemp = $_FILES['galFile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $imageError = $_FILES['galFile']['error'][$i];

            //Make sure it is an image
            if(in_array(end(explode(".", $imageName)), $allowed))
            {
                 //Where to upload image to
                 $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $imageName;
                 if (file_exists($uploadFile))
        {
            //What to do if file already exists
            //Append random number to the end
            $front = explode(".", $imageName);
            $randomNum = rand(1,100);
            $front[0] = $front[0].$randomNum;
            $imageName = $front[0].".".$front[1];
            $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $imageName;
        }
                  if(move_uploaded_file($imageTemp,$uploadFile))
                  {
                  //Add $imageName to DB
                   $query = "INSERT INTO galleryImages VALUES(\"0\",\"$lastInsert\",\"$imageName\",\"$i\")";
               mysql_query($query);
               reSizePic($uploadFile);
                  }
            }
}
```

Here is the GD code I had been using to resize:

```
function reSizePic($image)
{
$source_pic = $image;
$destination_pic = $image;
$max_width = 660;
$max_height = 500;

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_pic);
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($source_pic);

$x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
$y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

if(($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height))
{
    $tn_width = $width;
    $tn_height = $height;
}
elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height)
{
    $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
    $tn_width = $max_width;
}
else
{
    $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
    $tn_height = $max_height;
}

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width, $tn_height,$width,$height);

imagejpeg($tmp,$destination_pic,100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

And this is the ImageMagick code I am using to resize:

```
$resource = NewMagickWand(); 
MagickReadImage($resource,$image); 
MagickSetImageCompressionQuality( $resource, 100);
$resource = MagickTransformImage($resource,'0x0','660x500');
MagickWriteImage($resource, $image);
DestroyMagickWand($resource);
```

Comment: You're probably doing something inefficiently because ImageMagick should be able to handle 400kb images with no problem. How many are you trying to resize at once? Can you post your code?

Comment: I assume you're opening a file but not closing it or something to get that much memory usage. Post your code maybe?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on 200-400KB too much - 3.2 to 5megapixel cellphone cameras are common these days.

Comment: Both GD and ImageMagick should be able to handle fairly large files pretty easily. You code looks sound. In fact, I'm using GD routinely to resize 3-4 MB images. I can do a batch of a about 10 4 MB files in about 5-6 seconds on a 2ghz machine with 1.5 GBs RAM. Nothing special. It sounds like you have a configuration issue on your server not a programming error.

On a side note, you have some fairly serious database security issues going on there. Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: "with 1.5 GBs RAM. Nothing special." vs "the server has a 64 MB limit.". run a 64mb ini_set an try. check my answer for calculations.

Comment: I have tried to reset the limit, but the host does not allow it.  That is why I chose to try out ImageMagick.  I used the formula previously and found that the server was using about 90MB to convert one image and that was why GD was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pl.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg

> The memory required to load an image
>   using imagecreatefromjpeg() is a
>   function of the image's dimensions and
>   the images's bit depth, multipled by
>   an overhead. It can calculated from
>   this formula: Num bytes = Width *
>   Height * Bytes per pixel * Overhead
>   fudge factor Where Bytes per pixel =
>   Bit depth/8, or Bits per channel * Num
>   channels / 8.

That's about the GD part. Now the ImageMagick: have you tried a simpler approach:

```
$thumb = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$thumb->resizeImage($w,$h,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('thumb.jpg');
$thumb->destroy();
```

Comment: The above for ImageMagick did not work.  It says, "Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found"
I am using Hostgator and they have Magickwand installed, do you know if this means I can only use Magickwand commands?

Comment: Took this example from the docs comments, if you have the magick package installed, It shoud work, I think.

Comment: The code I have resizes the images fine for the first 15 images uploaded.  If I upload more than 15 it doesn't end so I believe it is something to do with the server and some sort of a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Please put up the following code on the top of your php file.

ini_set("memory_limit","500M");

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about this question, but is the following answer useful

[What is the best way to handle photo uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74315/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-photo-uploads)

Just in case it is **not**, ignore it.